# Como posicionar o geom_text acima do geom_errorbar?

Tags: r

Gostaria de ajuda para posicionar o label do geom_text (que no caso seria um teste de médias) exatamente acima de cada barra de erro, como fiz as barras de erro por tratamento, elas ficaram de tamanhos distintos, assim sempre tenho que ajustar conforme a maior barra, enquanto que nos tratamentos com menor barra de erro, acaba ficando um espaço grande da barra até o label e visualmente não fica bonito.

O script resumido:

````
IC = data.frame(
  "Fator1" = c(rep("A",4),
             rep("B",4)),
  "Fator2" = c("0","1","2","3"),
    "LL"= c(IC_A0$conf.int[1], 
          IC_A1$conf.int[1], 
          IC_A2$conf.int[1],
          IC_A3$conf.int[1],
          IC_B0$conf.int[1], 
          IC_B1$conf.int[1], 
          IC_B2$conf.int[1],
          IC_B3$conf.int[1]),
  "Mean" = c(IC_A0$estimate,
             IC_A1$estimate, 
             IC_A2$estimate,
             IC_A3$estimate,
             IC_B0$estimate,
             IC_B1$estimate, 
             IC_B2$estimate,
             IC_B3$estimate),
  "UL" = c(IC_A0$conf.int[2], 
          IC_A1$conf.int[2], 
          IC_A2$conf.int[2],
          IC_A3$conf.int[2],
          IC_B0$conf.int[2], 
          IC_B1$conf.int[2], 
          IC_B2$conf.int[2],
          IC_B3$conf.int[2]),
 "TK" = c("aB","aB","bB","aA",
          "aA","aC","bB","aC"))

ggplot(IC, aes(x = Fator2, y = Mean, fill = Fator1))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(
    ymax = UL,
    ymin = LL),
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    width = 0.2,
    lwd = 0.6,
    cex=1.2
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label=TK), family = "serif",
            vjust=-6.0, 
            position = position_dodge(0.9))```
````

Comment: Olá @Rosana MT, não é possível reproduzir o seu código. Veja dicas [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) para melhorar a sua pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Use para o texto a mesma coordenada da barra superior de erro, com a opção `nudge_y` para o texto não ficar sobreposto:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(2038)
media <- sample(10:20, 5)
dados <- data.frame(
  x = LETTERS[1:5],
  y = media,
  y.sup = media + rnorm(5, 3),
  y.inf = media - rnorm(5, 3))

ggplot(dados, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = y.sup, ymin = y.inf)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = y.sup, label = x), nudge_y = 1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Carlos, muito obrigada pela sua ajuda. Foi muito útil e deu certo!

Comment: @rosana-mt: [não precisa agradecer, apenas use o sistema do site para pontuar a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).